# How to call bash script that may request user input from another script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have two scripts one calls another and under some conditions that called script may request user input. At the moment I'm just executing this script but it is even doesn't wait for an input. How do I properly call this script and set pass the communication with a user to it?

Main script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

script_dir=$(dirname "${0}")
hook_name=$(basename "${0}")

hook_dir="${script_dir}/${hook_name}.d"

if [[ -d ${hook_dir} ]]; then
  for hook in "${hook_dir}"/*; do
    "${hook}"  "${@}"
    exit_code=${?}

    if [ ${exit_code} != 0 ]; then
      error=$(tput setaf 1)
      normal=$(tput sgr0)
      script_name=$(basename "${hook}")
      echo "${error}Hook ${hook_name} : ${script_name} failed!${normal}"
      exit ${exit_code}
    fi
  done
fi

exit 0
```

Called file:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=("hooks/install.sh" "hooks/install.bat")
changed=$(git diff --cached --name-only)

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  if [[ ${changed} == *"${file}"* ]]; then
    error=$(tput setaf 1)
    normal=$(tput sgr0)
    message="${error}You have changed one of the files that supposed to work identically!${normal}: [ ${files[*]} ]"
    echo "${message}"
    read -r -p "Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]: " response
    response=${response,,}
    if [[ $response =~ ^(no|n) ]] || [[ -z $response ]]; then
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
done

exit 0
```

Comment: Are you executing the script manually from an interactive shell or from something like a cron job? Ah, it's called by `git`, right?

Comment: @Kusalananda, this script is a git hook, that is called on a pre-commit stage by the git itself.

Comment: Then I'm assuming that standard input is redirected into it from `/dev/null` or something like that by `git`, so that `read` never manages to read anything. As I've never written Git hooks myself, I can't elaborate more about that.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Thank you for pointing it out, that the case might be that this script is called by git. Actually, it is perfectly answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10015707/6713260 . Not sure what to do with this question, I should search harder next time before asking=)